# XMPP Connection in seperate thread - Still gets closed by Android OS?

Tags: android, multithreading, xmpp, android-service, asmack

I've got an app with many many services (delivery application for businesses), which connects to an XMPP server to post reports. It's mainly working brilliantly. However, on the odd occasion when connecting over (1/3G) the connection takes too long and the OS kills the app. What's annoying me is that the connection is spawned by a service started by Alarm manager, and I'm using AndroidConnectionConfiguration (aSmack lib), which apparently spawns a seperate thread for connecting to get away from NetworkOnMainUIException. Yet, every so often, my app is still sent a sigabrt signal 6. Why is this happening? I'm not doing anything on the UI, or near it and thought that regardless of time, Android would leave it alone until it was finished or times out itself? Or am I wrong?

Is there anything else I can do to stop this happening? I don't care if XMPP is connected or not, as it will always retry and send when its able, but I can't have the app crashing.

**Edit** I should say that I'm using aSmack 0.8.10 - And Openfire 3.9.1. But they aren't the problem and work wonderfully well. It's only on the odd occasion that the connection takes too long and Android kills it.

**Edit 2** Some code:

```
package com.goosesys.dta_pta_test.Singletons;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.AndroidConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManagerListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackAndroid;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;

import android.content.Context;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.goosesys.dta_pta_test.MessageListenerService;
import com.goosesys.gooselib.Logging;
import com.goosesys.gooselib.Utilities.AppSettings;
import com.goosesys.gooselib.Utilities.Utility;

public class XmppConnector 
{
    private static XmppConnector instance;
    private static boolean isConnected = false;
    private static AndroidConnectionConfiguration acc;
    private static XMPPConnection xConnection;
    private static Context context;


    public static void init(Context contxt)
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new XmppConnector();
        }

        context = contxt;
    }

    public static XmppConnector getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    public static boolean connect() throws XMPPException
    {
        if(isConnected)
            return true;

        SmackAndroid.init(context);
        acc = new AndroidConnectionConfiguration(AppSettings.XMPP_SERVER_HOST,
                AppSettings.XMPP_SERVER_PORT, "Smack");
        acc.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
        xConnection = new XMPPConnection(acc);

        xConnection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener(){
            @Override
            public void reconnectionSuccessful()
            {
                Logging.Debug("XmppConnector", "...reconnected to XMPP Server");
            }

            @Override
            public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e)
            {
                Logging.Debug("XmppConnector", "...reconnection failed: " + e);
            }

            @Override
            public void reconnectingIn(int seconds)
            {
                Logging.Debug("XmppConnector", "...reconnecting in: " + seconds);
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e)
            {
                Logging.Debug("XmppConnector", "...connection closed on error: " + e);
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionClosed()
            {
                Logging.Debug("XmppConnector", "...connection closed");
            }                   
        });

        xConnection.connect();
        if(xConnection.isConnected())
        {
            isConnected = true;

            // LOGIN ONCE CONNECTED TO THE SERVER //
            xConnection.login(Utility.getAndroidID(context),
                    AppSettings.XMPP_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
            // CREATE CHAT MANAGER //
            xConnection.getChatManager().addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener(){
                @Override
                public void chatCreated(final Chat chat, boolean createdLocally)
                {
                    if(!createdLocally)
                        chat.addMessageListener(new MessageListenerService(context));
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            isConnected = false;
        }

        return isConnected;
    }

    public static boolean sendMessage(String jsonObj)
    {
        Message m = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObj, Message.class);
        if(m == null)
        {
            Logging.Error("XmppConnector", "Message object is null.. Aborting");
            return false;
        }

        if(isConnected)
        {
            xConnection.sendPacket(m);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and the small service that kicks it off:

public class BGCollectorProc extends IntentService
{
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

```
public BGCollectorProc() 
{
    super("BGCollectorProc");       
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{   
    Logging.Debug("BGCollectorProc", "Spinning...");    
    //dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getHelper(getApplicationContext());

    try
    {
        // initialise the connection
        XmppConnector.init(this);
        // get the static reference
        XmppConnector.getInstance();
        // connect to the server
        if(XmppConnector.connect())
        {
            Logging.Info("BGCollectorProc", "CONNECTED TO XMPP SERVER");
        }
    }
    catch(XMPPException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*
    // Worker thread area //
    try {
        postDeliveries();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    postGeoLogs();
    */

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: What would be really interesting here is the relevant snipped from the Android logs. Android kills processes when it needs to do so. But sticky services are restarted.

Comment: I appreciate that I didn't supply any logcat, but the only output I get just before is: libc - Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000000149 (code=0), thread 24939 (ys.dta_pta_test) - Didn't really think that was relevant as it's not overly helpful. My services aren't meant to spin all the time, so they're set to not sticky, and restarted once a minute via AlarmManager. What I'm now wondering is if I can specify a timeout (just shy of Android's sigabrt signal) to stop the app being killed?

Answer (score 1):

`SIGABRT` usually means that something fatal has happened within dalvik. It's not Android ActivityManager that kills your process. It's the VM that terminates itself because of a VM fault. Usually there will be more information about the fault. Maybe you didn't recognize the logs as related to the `SIGABRT`. At least I would expect to find some more information about the cause of the `SIGABRT` in the logs.

BTW: A service that holds an active XMPPConnection is an ideal candidate for a sticky Android service, that should be running as long as the XMPPConnection should be active.